# Issue uploading file from flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, powerapp, image-upload

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.matthewdevaney.com/power-apps-add-picture-control-and-save-to-sharepoint-library/) and all has gone well until I get to running the flow to upload the image.  The code in the tutorial reads:

```
'BlogImages:UploadPhotoToSharePoint'.Run(
 {
     contentBytes: img_SingleImage_Image.Image,
     name: Text(Now(), "yyMMddhhmmss")
 },
 txt_SingleImage_Caption.Text
)
```

The first line didn't quite work for me, I ended up with:

```
UploadKittyPic.Run(
{
    contentBytes: img_SingleImage_Image.Image,
    name: Text(Now(), "yyMMddhhmmss")
},
txt_SingleImage_Caption.Text
)
```

Ignore the fact the flow is named differently, that much I know.  PowerApps isn't allowing me to use the code as per the tutorial, the error I am getting is:

```
Invalid argument type(Record). Expecting a Text value instead.
```

I have tried every combination I can think of, but I can't get around this issue. The only way I can get PowerApps to compile is using this:

```
UploadKittyPic.Run(
 img_SingleImage_Image.Image
);

Navigate('Thumbnail Gallery Screen', Fade);
```

Then the flow fails, complaining that contentBytes hasn't been set.

EDIT**
Here is my flow:

[image]

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: How many inputs you have in power automate flow? You have to pass the inputs to flow in specific sequence.

Comment: @GaneshSanap - Question edited to show my flow

Comment: When you will type `FlowName.Run(` in the formula bar in power apps, it will show you the required inputs and the sequence. Try passing the values in that format. Let me know if this works. Quick question - Are both inputs required or file input is optional?

Comment: Also, try this: `UploadKittyPic.Run(
file:{
    contentBytes: img_SingleImage_Image.Image,
    name: Text(Now(), "yyMMddhhmmss")
},
txt_SingleImage_Caption.Text
)` **OR** this: `UploadKittyPic.Run(
txt_SingleImage_Caption.Text,
file:{
    contentBytes: img_SingleImage_Image.Image,
    name: Text(Now(), "yyMMddhhmmss")
}
)`

Comment: @GaneshSanap - Thanks for your help, greatly appreciated.  I now have it uploading, but I am unable to see the picture that has been uploaded to SharePoint (I can see the record, but the photo is not viewable).  I will do some more testing shortly....

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you will type `FlowName.Run(` in the formula bar in Power Apps, it will show you the required inputs and the sequence like below:

[image]

Try passing the values in that format.

---

Also, try using formula like this:

```
UploadKittyPic.Run(
    file:{
        contentBytes: img_SingleImage_Image.Image,
        name: Text(Now(), "yyMMddhhmmss")
    },
    txt_SingleImage_Caption.Text
)
```

OR

```
UploadKittyPic.Run(
    txt_SingleImage_Caption.Text,
    file:{
        contentBytes: img_SingleImage_Image.Image,
        name: Text(Now(), "yyMMddhhmmss")
    }
)
```